# image movement along a defined path in android

Tags: android

I am making a learning game for teaching numbers to kindergarten kids. It requires some animation like [this](http://www.turtlediary.com/preschool-games/math-games/learn-numbers.html) but I am failing in achieving this animation smoothly in canvas.

I want exactly the same animation appearing using this dotted line.

Please guide me to perform exactly this type of animation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

- a loop
- path definition

The loop should update current image position and rotation. Then draw the updated animation on a screen. You can just override dispatchDraw method and call invalidate at the very end of it. You can update position right before drawing. Your case is similar to game programming, so you can look for articles about game loops.

Path definition should allow you to calculate position depending on time. Fo example you can use Bezier curves. Bezier curve equation is parametric and the parameter is 'time'. Using the animation time gives you smooth movement along the path.

Example of a generic game loop: http://www.gameprogblog.com/generic-game-loop/

Bezier curve: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    PointF pos = getBezierPos(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
    drawImage(pos);
    invalidate();
}
```